# how do I specify the opacity to a specific region

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As you can see theres a opacity slider. I want to modify it in a way wherein only the opacity of the windows change and nothing else. Much like this tint adjuster below:
[tint-adjuster](https://www.tinting-laws.com/tint-tester/tint-tester.htm)

```js
$('#bgopacity').on('input', function (value) {
    $('.background-color').css({
        opacity: $(this).val() * '.01'
    });
});
```

```css
.background-color {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url("https://c8.alamy.com/comp/KCKGB8/classic-german-car-side-view-isolated-on-white-KCKGB8.jpg");
    opacity: .5;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>VLT</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="35" min="0" max="70" step="10" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">35</output>
</form>


<div class="background-color">
</div>
```

Comment: You probably need to use canvas

Comment: You can either use a canvas or put the windows into a seperate image and apply the change to the window image. The example you showed uses 2 images on top of eachother (one with a light window and one with a dark window) and applies a opacity to the one of them.

Comment: @Reyno actually its just one image whose opacity can be varied.

Comment: @epascarello can you please post the solution. I did try it out by using canvas  but wasnt able to figure out

Comment: @DipanGhosh yes ok multiple images are combined into one, but showed based on a background position. He still uses 2 divs with the image and just hides one slowly with opacity

Comment: I do not have all day to write it, it is not a simple thing. Simple solution is what was proposed. Edit the image to only have the windows, make the rest transparent and toggle the opacity.

Comment: @epascarello thankyou for your  time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using two divs with a background image on top of eachother. (Just like the example you showed)

For demo purposes i added a grayscale instead of a separate image with darker windows.

```js
$('#bgopacity').on('input', function (value) {
    $('.bottom').css({
        opacity: $(this).val() * '.01'
    });
});
```

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url("https://c8.alamy.com/comp/KCKGB8/classic-german-car-side-view-isolated-on-white-KCKGB8.jpg");
}

.bottom {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>VLT</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="100" min="0" max="100" step="10" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">100</output>
</form>


<div class="background">
  <div class="bg top"></div>
  <div class="bg bottom"></div>
</div>
```